# Pyhon didn't show on console a function

Tags: python, function, printing, command, line

I have this function in python:

```
def Alex():
        print ("Numele si prenumele: Alex Popescu.")
        print ("Varsta: 27 ani.")
        print ("Salariu: €1750 ")
        print ("Post: Tirist.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
        Alex()
```

When I'm calling the function, python doesn't print the function  [CODE AND COMMAND LINE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5kQY.png)

Comment: The code you posted works fine, the code in the screenshot has the `if __name__...` check indented into the function `Alex`.

Comment: From your screenshot, the problem is that `input` always returns a string. When you type `1`, as shown, the variable holds not the integer `1`, but the string `"1"`

Comment: Check for indentation in a modern editor such as sublime text or vs code.

Comment: your code sample and screenshot mismatches. Please fix it.

Comment: Alternatively you can consider to use Python instead of Pyhon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value returned by input is always string even if someone type only digits like '1'.

```
actiune = input('Ce actiune doriti sa faceti?(1-4): ')

if actiune == '1':
    def Alex():
        print ("Numele si prenumele: Alex Popescu.")
        print ("Varsta: 27 ani.")
        print ("Salariu: €1750 ")
        print ("Post: Tirist.")
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Alex()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `input` returns a string, and you compare that string with an integer in the code in the picture. `actinue = int(actinue)` should fix it. Alternatively you might compare it with `"1"` instead of `1`.